# Execution failed for task ':hVFhirApp:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I know that this is an error that it has been asked in a question before but I havent found any answer that suits me.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hvfhirapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21

        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

configurations{
    compile.exclude module: 'commons-codec'
    compile.exclude module: 'javax.json'

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidsdksimplexml')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-base:1.1'
    compile 'ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-structures-dstu2:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

As you can see I have entered the multiDexEnabled = true and I have also added the dependcy of MultiDex + the line in my manifest's application.

Also my exact error in the stack trace in gradle console is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hVFhirApp:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Also what I would like to add is the fact that when I remove the excludes in my dependencies bracket the error that shows up is

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hVFhirApp:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.class
```

and that's why I exclude them

Any help would be of much appreciation.
Thank you in advance

Comment: may be some classes are in conflict

Comment: How can I find which classes are in conflict?

Comment: are you using any jar file?

Comment: view your logcat carefully you can find it, i think compile.exclude module: 'javax.json' line is not working

Comment: No, I'm not using any jar file... Everything that I import are in my gradle dependencies... As for my logcat it doesn't say anything about conflicting classes. Also my javax.json exclude works because if i remove it, it throws a ZipException: duplicate entry like the one I mentioned above for a Json class

Answer (score 0):

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Add this to your gradle and clean the entire the project and build.Still if it is not working then uninstall JAVA from your machine and reinstall again

Comment: No, it didn't work... I have 64 bit Java architecture? Can this be a problem?